# Ratio = 1 or Difference = 0

Tags: hypothesis-testing, variance

In two-sample testing, a standard way of examining for differences in variance is testing a null hypothesis that the ratio of two variances is 1. Let's set up the problem.

Why not test that the difference is zero? Sure, we can't test against the F-distribution, but if we construct a distribution of the difference, such as by doing permutation testing, that seems totally legitimate.

More broadly (not just focused on variance), what would be the advantages and disadvantages of testing $\theta_0 - \theta_1 = 0$ versus $\dfrac{\theta_0}{\theta_1}=1$? Let’s say that $\theta_i$ is mean, median, variance, standard deviation, IQR, skewness, kurtosis, Pearson correlation (for bivariate variables), Spearman correlation (again, bivariate), or [Hoeffding’s independence statistic](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hoeffding%27s_independence_test) (again, bivariate). All I can see is that we could get into trouble if we expect (or allow for) either $\theta$ to be zero or for the $\theta$s to have different signs. Perhaps if neither of those are concerns (such as with variance), we would prefer to check the ratio.

(I don’t necessarily care about those ten, but I’m curious what happens for a wide range of parameters, not just variances.)

Comment: With traditional two-sample tests, the preference is to look at the difference $\theta_1 - \theta_2$ when $\theta$ is a location parameter (e.g., normal mean, median, 23rd quantile), and at the ratio $\theta_1/\theta_2$ when $\theta$ is a scale parameter (e.g., normal SD, IQR, exponential mean). // With computationally intensive tests that do not assume normal or another particular family of distributions (based on simulated permutation, bootstrap) one may not _know_ whether the parameter/measure/metric of interest refers to location, scale, or neither (correlation. coefficient of variation.)

Comment: The sampling distribution of the parameters tells you the answer: ideally, the distribution of the metric you use to compare the parameters should be approximately symmetric and, when you are relying on asymptotic approximations to Normality, should be close to Normally distributed.

Comment: @whuber Do you mean to pick, if I can, a null hypothesis so that the test statistic is symmetric and normal?

Comment: @Dave Not quite.  As in the examples of this question, the null hypotheses are equivalent: if you let $\delta$ be any metric, then (axiomatically) $\theta_1=\theta_0$ if and only if $\delta(\theta_1,\theta_0)=0.$ The idea is to select a $\delta$ for which the sampling distribution of the estimate $\hat\delta(\theta_1,\theta_0)$ is "well behaved."